# How to add Navigation bar to SharePoint home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, navigation, top-link-bar, homepage

Hi All I am looking to add a navigation bar to the top of my home page on SharePoint there doesn't appear to a be a web part option for this, could anyone shed some light? Also when looking under navigation i only see quicklaunch, but the only option here is to mark or unmark. Thanks

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I am using the online sharePoint I have no option for top link navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top link navigation bar cannot be a web part to be added in the home page.

Go to site settings, "Edit links" will show in the top link navigation bar, then you could edit top link navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have already tried to update here but do not have top link available? Just quick launch any further ideas?